# Small file, simple scene, but long render times?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

**Question: How can I achieve a shorter render time in cycles of my simple scene?**

I am having issues rendering a very small and simple scene in Blender. I have made complex scenes before in Blender that render in 10 seconds but this scene takes 27 seconds to render.

I have tried adjusting the sampling, denoising, light paths, clamping, caustics, persistent data, etc.. but it still takes close to 30 seconds to render a single frame.

See screenshots of my settings and a rendered example. I also have a google drive link with original file if you want to play around with it. [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U-6fOZOvgHWRwJkNxj_RXQwbXz0nVRwF?usp=sharing).

Any direction helps. Thank you!

[image: Computer Specifications]

[image: Preferences Information]

[image: Render Properties Panel]

[image: Render Properties Panel Continued]

[image: Render time and Memory Screenshot]

[image: Render Example]

Comment: Please embed your images directly into your question rather than posting a link to "a bunch of screenshots". If your question is accessed in future it's very likely that the link won't exist. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have updated the post for clarity. Thank you for commenting